# Is SQLite Foreign Keys system inverted?

Tags: foreign-key, sqlite

I think I'm misunderstanding the sqlite FK system (or maybe the whole SQL FK system at all ?)

I have a table **DOMAINE** :

```
CREATE TABLE "DOMAINE" (
    "DOM_DOMAINE"   TEXT,
    "DOM_NEWNAME"   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("DOM_DOMAINE"),
    FOREIGN KEY("DOM_DOMAINE") REFERENCES "SOURCE_GMAO"("SRC_DOMAINE")
```

And a table **SOURCE_GMAO** :

```
CREATE TABLE "SOURCE_GMAO" (
    "SRC_OT"    INTEGER,
    ...
    "SRC_DOMAINE"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("SRC_OT")
)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that I want to be able to create a DOMAINE only if the DOM_DOMAINE (which has to be the PK too) exists in the table SOURCE_GMAO.

For example, if any row in SOURCE_GMAO contains the SRC_DOMAINE = "mechanical", I have to be able to create row in DOMAINE like that :

```
INSERT INTO DOMAINE(DOM_DOMAINE, DOM_NEWNAME) VALUES("mechanical", "B103")
```

But with my actual settings I can create any DOMAINE I want, but I can't create a SOURCE_GMAO product because I get this error :

> foreign key mismatch - "DOMAINE" referencing "SOURCE_GMAO"

I'm new to SQLite, I always used SQL Server and never had any problem with FK.

What's the problem here ? Is the SQLite system inverted or did I always understood the FK system incorrectly ?

Comment: 1. *"but I can't create a SOURCE_GMAO product because I get this error : ..."* You haven't showed us what statement produces the error.

Comment: Sorry ! I used the DB Browser for SQLite to INSERT it with the UI

Comment: 2. You have a foreign key that `REFERENCES "SOURCE_GMAO"("SRC_DOMAINE")` but there is no PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint on `"SOURCE_GMAO"("SRC_DOMAINE")` as fas as we can see. Either that FOREIGN KEY was not created and you got an error or the FKs are completely disabled in your SQLIte setup.

Comment: See section 2 (enabling foreign key support) in: https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: Ok that's a pretty noob error we have here haha... I followed the client Database Design and totally forgot that we can only references either a UNIQUE or PK fields... Thanks for your time, I'll have to call them tomorrow, their database schema is wrong. Thanks again !